# NVIDIA-SMI couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver in Nvidia GeForce 840M

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have installed Nvidia GeForce 840M proprietary drivers by using the following command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510
```

I faced no problem in installing it. After rebooting I tried to run the following  command:

```
nvidia-semi
```

to check if its working or not. It shows,

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Can anyone help what might be the problem?

Comment: Let the ubuntu-drivers select the driver your hardware can use, instead of just picking the latest driver. See which one with ubuntu-drivers list then use the ubuntu-drivers install command.Clean out the 510 driver before the install.

Comment: @ubfan1 can you recommend the command or link to the procedure to do that?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/449693/how-to-change-graphic-card-driver-using-ubuntu-drivers or search this site for ubuntu-drivers.  The Software and Updates program has a tab, Additional Drivers, which will also let you choose the "recommended" driver.